# Laravel get an array from a table and search the array in another table

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm working on a project with laravel and I have to ask to database some queries that have to return an array. This is the code that I have

Logged as a teacher:

```
$teacher= Teacher_Admin::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$grades = Grade::where('id_depar', $teacher->id_depar)->get(); //3 grades         
$studients_grades = Studient_Grades::where('id_grade', $grades->id)->get(); //5 studient
$studients = Studient::where('id', $studients_grades->id_studient)->get(); //5 studient
$user = User::where('range', 2)->get();//5 users
```

What I'm trying to do is look for all the studients that are enrolled on a grade that is on the department of the teacher, e.g. Departments: IT, Chemistry. In IT department we have two Grades: Frontent Development and Backend Development. And I have 30 studient per grade. How I can get the 60 studients?

If you need more code please ask, this is my first question and I'm not sure how to do this 

Thanks in advice

Comment: With Laravel ORM called Eloquent you can do relationships, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships , there is also video course on Laracast for relationships https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/16 , hope it will helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. When I start receiving get() answers, it returns a multiple array so I have to parse to something like this

```
$teacher= Teacher_Admin::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$grades = Grade::where('id_depar', $teacher->id_depar)->get();
$id_grades = []
foreach ($grades as $grade){
    $id_grades = $grade->id
}
$studients_grades = Studient_Grades::whereIn('id_grade', $id_grades)->get();
```

I was able to work with this :) Hope to help someone someday